# Coordinate auto completion in Minecraft Win 10

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When using commands in Minecraft Java Edition (e.g. /fill), before opening the chat window I normally just have to aim the crosshair to a block, then open the chat window and type in the command. Now when I press the **Tab** key 3 times, Minecraft auto completes the coordinates of the aimed block itself.

However this does not seem to work in Win 10 edition. Am I doing something wrong here or is this really not possible there?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: @TheOnlyMrCat You can write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Tab to autocomplete aimed coordinates only works on the Java edition, not the Windows 10 edition.